# Software to draw CPM diagrams like this

Tags: project-management, diagram

As the title says, I've been searching high and low all over the Internet for a program - online or offline, Windows or Linux, it doesn't matter - that would allow drawing CPM diagrams which look like this

[image]

(source: this [article](https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/new-pert-templates-aoa-and-aon-on-creately/) by Creately). Apparently Creately offers this, but I'd like it to:

- be somewhat smart and keep added nodes connected, instead of having to drag separate circles and lines around the canvas, similar to what StarUML, JFLAP and yEd do in respective domains, but with CPM
- be able to automatically generate such a CPM diagram based on a list of activities like one in MS Project
- automatically perform CPM analysis (fill in those lower halves) and highlight critical path

Comment: Possibly ... GraphViz?

Comment: Hmm, looks more like a library than a program available to end-users.

Comment: Graphviz? It is a standalone program, not a library

Comment: Maybe my wording was bad. It indeed is a program, but I'm having a hard time finding a GUI inside the GraphViz package. Gephi seems closest to something like that, but I'm not sure it features a CPM template.

Comment: Why would you want a GUI? It's great strength is that it turns text into diagrams - it is not a drawing program in the conventional sense. If you want a HUI, see http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/  and https://portableapps.com/node/38245 and there is an MS Visual Studio plugin which I do not have a URL for